# How to get information from html in R?

Tags: html, r

I want to get information about price from this page: https://www.coffeedesk.pl/product/16632/Espresso-Miesiaca-Lacava-Etiopia-Yirgacheffe-Rocko-Mountain-1Kg

My code

```
url <-"https://www.coffeedesk.pl/product/16632/Espresso-Miesiaca-Lacava-Etiopia-Yirgacheffe-Rocko-Mountain-1Kg"
x <- xml2::read_html(url)
price<-x%>% html_node('span.product-price smaller-price') %>%
  html_text()
```

but it returns NA
What can I do?

Answer (score 0):

You have a space in your html statement when you really need to have a period. Try `html_node('span.product-price.smaller-price')` in your code and see if that works.